# mysqlx unable to connect with database using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have installed the latest mysql connector for Python to connect with MySQL Shell. When I tried to connect MySQL Shell using Python getting below error,

```
>>> import mysqlx
>>> mysqlx.get_session("mysqlx://root:<passsword>@localhost:3306/mySchema")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/mysqlx/__init__.py", line 193, in get_session
    return XSession(settings)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/mysqlx/connection.py", line 464, in __init__
    self._connection.connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/mysqlx/connection.py", line 328, in connect
    return super(XConnection, self).connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/mysqlx/connection.py", line 160, in connect
    self._handle_capabilities()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/mysqlx/connection.py", line 164, in _handle_capabilities
    data = self.protocol.get_capabilites().capabilities
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/mysqlx/protocol.py", line 88, in get_capabilites
    return self._reader.read_message()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/mysqlx/protocol.py", line 56, in read_message
    return self._read_message()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/mysqlx/protocol.py", line 62, in _read_message
    raise ProgrammingError("The connected server does not have the "
mysqlx.errors.ProgrammingError: The connected server does not have the MySQL X protocol plugin enabled
>>>
```

Am sure that X plugin is enabled, since I was able to read,write,delete collections using mysqlsh. Not sure why am getting this error and any help suggestion would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should connect to X protocol port 33060. 3306 is a classic protocol.